# How to remove comma or any characters from Python dataframe column name

Tags: python, dataframe

I was importing 400+ csv files with 50+ columns into data frame, each file having different columns but some column name contains comma ',', I want to remove it, please help on this.

```
data = pd.read_csv('D://ABC//WID_AM_MacroData.csv',delimiter=';').loc[[6]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use :

```
data.columns = [col.replace(',', '') for col in data.columns]
```

Comment: @HH1 or even `data.columns = data.columns.str.replace(',', '')`

Comment: @ Jon Clements, simple one...tq